# set Display property None In Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to set display property none with on click event. If I am using querySelectorAll then it's applyng on all if I click on first button and other buttons are not working. I am New to JavaScript Here is my code.

```js
let div = document.querySelector('.cross')
            div.addEventListener('click',closeDiv);

            function closeDiv() {
                let closeBy = document.querySelectorAll('div');
                closeBy.forEach(element => {
                   element.classList.add('display')
                });
                }
```

```css
div{
            border: 1px solid green;
            margin: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px
        }

        .cross {
            border: 1px solid red;
            border-radius: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 27px;
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .cross:hover {
            background-color: greenyellow;
            border: 1px solid greenyellow;
            color: red;
        }

        .display{
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<div>
        <button class="cross">X</button>
        <h3>First</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam atque dignissimos, delectus facere vero quia, similique voluptatem adipisci nobis iusto suscipit. Consequuntur officia earum iure! Consequatur iusto soluta ut alias atque blanditiis, optio maiores ullam, cum quibusdam, adipisci hic ducimus sed nam quas. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="cross">X</button>
        <h3>Second</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam atque dignissimos, delectus facere vero quia, similique voluptatem adipisci nobis iusto suscipit. Consequuntur officia earum iure! Consequatur iusto soluta ut alias atque blanditiis, optio maiores ullam, cum quibusdam, adipisci hic ducimus sed nam quas. </p></div>
    <div>
```

Comment: You want to set the display to none just from the div that contains the button, correct?

Answer (score 0):

solution for clicking a div and its parent div will hide

Step 1: add function closeDiv() to every div which are responsible to closing div

```
<div>
  <button class="cross" onClick="closeDiv(event)">X</button>
  <h3>First</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam atque dignissimos, delectus facere vero quia, similique voluptatem adipisci nobis iusto suscipit. Consequuntur officia earum iure! Consequatur iusto soluta ut alias atque blanditiis, optio maiores ullam, cum quibusdam, adipisci hic ducimus sed nam quas. </p>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="cross"  onClick="closeDiv(event)">X</button>
  <h3>Second</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam atque dignissimos, delectus facere vero quia, similique voluptatem adipisci nobis iusto suscipit. Consequuntur officia earum iure! Consequatur iusto soluta ut alias atque blanditiis, optio maiores ullam, cum quibusdam, adipisci hic ducimus sed nam quas. </p>
</div>
<div> // This line is incorrect in your code
```

Step 2: add functional things in side closeDiv function

```
function closeDiv(event) {
  let wrapperDiv = event.target.parentNode
  wrapperDiv.style.display = "none"
}
```

[Check the full code here](https://jsfiddle.net/thainq00/bvLm9ucw/4/)

Hope this helps and feel free to comment below if this answer is not enough to you.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the javascript code

```js
let cross = document.querySelectorAll('.cross')

cross.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    this.parentElement.style.display = 'none' // get parent
  })
})
```

```css
Eu quero definir nenhuma propriedade de exibição no evento click. Se eu estiver usando o querySelectorAll, será aplicado a todos se clicar no primeiro botão e outros botões não estiverem funcionando. Eu sou novo no JavaScript Aqui está o meu código.

let div = document.querySelector('.cross')
            div.addEventListener('click',closeDiv);

            function closeDiv() {
                let closeBy = document.querySelectorAll('div');
                closeBy.forEach(element => {
                   element.classList.add('display')
                });
                }
div{
            border: 1px solid green;
            margin: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px
        }

        .cross {
            border: 1px solid red;
            border-radius: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 27px;
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .cross:hover {
            background-color: greenyellow;
            border: 1px solid greenyellow;
            color: red;
        }

        .display{
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<div>
        <button class="cross">X</button>
        <h3>First</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam atque dignissimos, delectus facere vero quia, similique voluptatem adipisci nobis iusto suscipit. Consequuntur officia earum iure! Consequatur iusto soluta ut alias atque blanditiis, optio maiores ullam, cum quibusdam, adipisci hic ducimus sed nam quas. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="cross">X</button>
        <h3>Second</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam atque dignissimos, delectus facere vero quia, similique voluptatem adipisci nobis iusto suscipit. Consequuntur officia earum iure! Consequatur iusto soluta ut alias atque blanditiis, optio maiores ullam, cum quibusdam, adipisci hic ducimus sed nam quas. </p></div>
    <div>
```

Use parentElement to get the parent element

Answer (score 0):

I'd use dataset attributes so each button knows what it closes.
In current example you could target parent object, but I prefer using dataset attributes because this can be applied even if close button gets nested deeper and div isn't direct parent anymore

```js
let div = document.querySelectorAll('.cross')
div.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click',closeDiv);
});


function closeDiv() {
    let parentMessageId = this.dataset.parentmessage;
    let closeBy = document.querySelectorAll('[data-message="'+parentMessageId+'"]');
    closeBy.forEach(element => {
        element.classList.add('display-hidden')
    });
}
```

```css
div{
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px
}

.cross {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 27px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cross:hover {
    background-color: greenyellow;
    border: 1px solid greenyellow;
    color: red;
}

.display-hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div data-message="1">
    <button data-parentmessage="1" class="cross">X</button>
    <h3>First</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam atque dignissimos, delectus facere vero quia, similique voluptatem adipisci nobis iusto suscipit. Consequuntur officia earum iure! Consequatur iusto soluta ut alias atque blanditiis, optio maiores ullam, cum quibusdam, adipisci hic ducimus sed nam quas. </p>
</div>
<div data-message="2">
    <button data-parentmessage="2" class="cross">X</button>
    <h3>Second</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam atque dignissimos, delectus facere vero quia, similique voluptatem adipisci nobis iusto suscipit. Consequuntur officia earum iure! Consequatur iusto soluta ut alias atque blanditiis, optio maiores ullam, cum quibusdam, adipisci hic ducimus sed nam quas. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, @NoOorZ24 @Quang Thái @Aks Jacoves thanks for you reply as a beginner i learned new method from you all. But I want to get it solved by using for, foreach or for of loop by adding class only. I am doing some mistake in my code but not able to find it out my code is                                                                                                      
 `function closeDiv() { let closeBy = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  for (const iterator of closeBy) {
  iterator.classList.add('display'); } }`

Comment: You can't really close one of them like that because you need to hide specific element, but you can't target specific element by querying element tag like `<div>` or a class. You need specific selector like id, data attribute or `element.parentNode` to target a parent